# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected string In JQuery in line 3

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, node.js

Im getting this error:  Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected string login.js:3 line

Login.js file:

```
(function ($) {
    'use strict';
    import './js/db';
    var gomb = $('.validate-form')
    $('.validate-form').on('submit',function(){
        alert("MEGNYOM!")
    });
})(jQuery);
```

[image]

Comment: [import - JavaScript | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import)

Comment: @melancia import '/modules/my-module.js'; this is valid

Comment: Not working :( Im getting the same error: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected string Line: 3

Comment: @SandrinJoy good point. Now it makes me think the issue is not on this file but on the one being imported?

Comment: @CsanádSenk to import files in a node server webapp , you have to do an extra step , by telling the server js file that u require this particular file/folder . Usually we devolopers use static variable to access those files thne

Comment: are you using express library for your project?

Comment: Yes but now i konow how to fix this error thanks for replies!